# Excel ODBC link to SQL Query for results between to dates

Tags: mysql, excel, vba, odbc

I'm running Excel 2016 on a Windows 10 Pro computer.  I have set up an ODBC connection from Excel to an external MariaDB SQL database. My VBA macro is mostly working the way I want, but I'm having problems selecting records between two dates.  This SQL statement works:

```
SELECT Date_Time, ChargerSt FROM `MyDBx`.`table` WHERE (Date_Time>{ts '2019-06-01 00:00:00'}) ORDER BY Date_Time;
```

However, I have not been able to get any combination of `WHERE` clauses using `BETWEEN date1 AND date2`; the above in combination with `Date_Time<{ts '2019-06-11 00:00:00'}` to work. The format of `Date_Time` in the SQL database in `yyyy-mm-dd`.

I'm inputting the dates like this:

```
firstdate = InputBox("Enter starting date (yyyy-mm-dd)")
seconddate = Format((DateValue(firstdate) - 7#), "yyyy-mm-dd")
```

and the VBA code for the SQL statement looks like this

```
"SELECT Date_Time, ChargerSt FROM `MyDBx`.`table` " _
 & "WHERE (Date_Time>{ts '" & firstdate & " 00:00:00'})" & " ORDER BY Date_Time"
```

This is probably really simple and only displays my lack of experience with SQL, but I'm trying to do and learn.

Comment: `BETWEEN` can be done also as `date >= StartDate AND date <= EndDate`. would that work for you?

Comment: I think that was one of the alternate code I tried.  I'll give it another try.

Comment: Typing errors in all cases!!!  I had Data-Type instead of Data_Type..  Both ways are working now.  As I said "a really simple" answer.

Comment: Glad it works for you, it was hard to point out to something that I couldn't see in your question (`Data-Type`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you solved your situation, consider parameterization in your ODBC connection which is the preferred way of running SQL at application layer such as VBA. With parameterization you avoid the need to concatenate or punctuate and it is recommended in the general programming industry beyond VBA (e.g., Java, Python, PHP) or MariaDB (Oracle, SQL Server, Postgres).

Below assumes you use ADO in Excel and runs late-binding on the module.

```vb
Public Sub RunSQL()   
    Dim firstdate As Date, seconddate As Date
    Dim sql as String, conn As Object, cmd As Object, rst As Object
    Const adCmdText = 1, adParamInput = 1, adDate = 7

    firstdate = DateValue(InputBox("Enter starting date (yyyy-mm-dd)"))
    seconddate = firstdate - 7

    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set rst = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    conn.Open "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver};host=hostname;" _
               & "database=databasename;UID=username;PWD=****"

    ' PREPARED STATEMENT (NO DATA)
    sql = "SELECT Date_Time, ChargerSt FROM `MyDBx`.`table` WHERE `DateTime` BETWEEN ? AND ?"
    ' CONFIGURE ADO COMMAND
    Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    With cmd
        .ActiveConnection = conn
        .CommandText = sql
        .CommandType = adCmdText
        ' BIND DATE VALUES
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("start_param", adDate, adParamInput, , firstdate)
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("start_param", adDate, adParamInput, , seconddate)
        ' CREATE RECORDSET
        Set rst = .Execute
    End With

    '... USE RECORDSET

    rst.Close
    Set rst = Nothing: Set cmd = Nothing: Set conn = Nothing    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for t he lesson. I'm a bit of a beginner at this and use the macros recorder to get me started.  I will study and learn from your comments. Thanks again.